# Simulating a moving catheter inside a human heart

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, simulation

I'm trying to simulate a moving catheter inside a human heart. I want to accurately model the behaviour of the catheter and I assume the heart to be solid. What I want is, when the catheter hits the wall, it should bend and move, instead of going through the wall.
catheter is modelled as a discrete rod with 4 particles.

I am planning to use Position Based Dynamics (PBD) for the simulations. Is this the best/simplest simulation framework to use? If not, which framework would suit the setup best?

Comment: This question might be a better fit on GameDev.se. But I'm not 100% sure so I'm not going to take any action on it right now. Simulation *per se* is not graphics IMO, but there is quite a bit of overlap.

Comment: @luserdroog thank you for your feedback. I posted a more updated question in GameDev.se. If you think it's relevant, I can post it here as well
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/201685/simulating-a-moving-catheter-inside-an-organ